# Customize nal in h264 encoder library

Tags: h.264, rtsp

I have to encode a video in h264,then transmit it over rtsp,but i have to add an additional nal unit of type unknown,then i have to decode that frames and get the nal unit of type unknown.Someone knows some library that can help me?Possibly in c,java or python

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown"? If you just want to transmit metadata, you can use the SEI NAL unit type.

Comment: The NAL units can contain different unit types, and if a player is unable to
understand a NAL Unit Type (NUT) it can skip it. In table 1 are shown some
of the most relevant NUTs.

6 Supplemental enhancement information (SEI) Non-VCL Non-VCL

12 Filler data Non-VCL Non-VCL

14 Prefix NAL unit Non-VCL Variable

24 · · · 31 Unspecified Non-VCL Non-VCL

 I want a unit type from 24 to 31 because if a player is unable to
understand a NAL Unit Type (NUT) it can skip it

Comment: you still need help with this one?

Comment: yes,i'm still searching for a solution

Answer (score -1):

It seems very unclear what you mean with the "unknown" NAL type, but generally you should look at [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org), it should suit your needs. It is a C library and i think there are 3rd party python bindings as well.